# Sort Objects in Array by Multiple Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am new to js and trying to sort an array of objects by two fields - starting with the first property, and then by the second property.  Both properties are numbers.

The data is:

```
var homes = [{
   "h_id": "3",
   "minimumorder": "12",
   "price": "17"
    }, {
   "h_id": "4",
   "minimumorder": "1",
   "price": "20"
}, {
   "h_id": "5",
   "minimumorder": "1",
   "price": "18.10"
}
```

There are more objects in the array, this is a simplified example. The below code ALMOST gets me there, but for the minimumorder property it puts 12 after 1 instead of after 6:

```
cmp = function(a, b) {
    parseFloat(a);
    parseFloat(b);
    if (a > b) return +1;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
}

homes.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return cmp(a.minimumorder,b.minimumorder) || cmp(a.price,b.price)
})
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/martellalex/cvXT4/1/).

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated, as I've been googling and tinkering for hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: || cmp(a.price,b.price) is an elegant fallback when minimumorder returns 0. Nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reassign the parsed value back to `a` and `b`:

```
a = parseFloat(a);
b = parseFloat(b);
```

Otherwise it ends up comparing strings, and `12` occurs after `1` lexically, just like the word `at` comes after `a` in the dictionary.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvXT4/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Well,

You should use a code like this:

```
function sortHomes(homes)
{
 var temp_homes = new Array();
 var new_homes = new Array();

 for(var i = 0; i < homes.length; i++) temp_homes[i] = homes[i];

 var maximum = 0, minimum;

 for(i = 0; i < temp_homes.length; i++) maximum = Math.max(maximum, temp_homes.minimumorder);

 var min_price, j, k, indexes, price_indexes;

 for(i = 0; i < temp_homes.length; i++){
  minimum = maximum;
  for(j = 0; j < temp_homes.length; j++){
   minimum = Math.min(minimum, temp_homes[j].minimumorder);
  }
  indexes = getIndexes(temp_homes, minimum, "minimumorder");
  if(indexes.length == 1){
   new_homes.push(temp_homes[indexes[0]]);
   temp_homes[indexes[0]].minimumorder = maximum + 1;
  }
  else{
   for(j = 0; j < indexes.length; j++){
    min_price = maximum;
    for(k = 0; k < indexes.length; k++){
     min_price = Math.min(min_price, temp_homes[indexes[k]].price);
    }
    price_indexes = getIndexes(temp_homes, min_price, "price");
    for(k = 0; k < price_indexes.length; k++){
     new_homes.push(temp_homes[price_indexes[k]]);
     temp_homes[price_indexes[k]].price = maximum + 1;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

function getIndexes(arr, el, name)
{
 var indexes = new Array();
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) if(arr[i][name] == el) indexes.push(i);
 return indexes;
}
```

It should work.
If it doesn't, please inform me about it.

Oh, and in order to sort homes, just use:

homes = sortHomes(homes);